# SSIS Dynamic Data Flows

Tags: ssis

I want to create above thirty dynamic data flows i.e. there are about thirty source tables i.e. sourcetable1, sourcetable2, sourcetable3 etc and about thirty destination tables i.e. destinationtable1, destinationtable2, destinationtable3 etc.

Sourcetable1 will map to destination table1, sourcetable2 will map to destinationtable2 etc.  The source tables have varying number of columns and varying data types.  There are millions of rows in every table.  The tables that are mapped will obviously have the same number of columns and same number of data types.

I believe I have to do this by creating a dynamic package.  Can I create a dynamic package inside a script task of an SSIS package? Is there any guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [BIML](http://bimlscript.com/), this example, [Extract All Tables](https://varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Extract+All+Tables), is pretty self explanatory and while BIML has its own unique quirks it can make you life so much more easy.

Comment: Also, you can do this with C# and the integration services API, if you are a programmer.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this. +1.